# Как настроить видеотрансляцию на своем сайте в Full HD?

Tags: веб-программирование, видео, онлайн-трансляция

создаем сайт и нужно на нем настроить видеотрансляцию в хорошем разрешении (минимум Full HD) для показа концертов.
Пробовали на flashphoner (https://flashphoner.com) и  сервис Amazon AWS. Настроить их так и не получилось.
Может есть не дорогие провайдеры, чтоб не было в них рекламы? Или все таки лучше самим настроить? А если самим, то какие использовать сервера?

Прошу подсказать наилучшее решение данной проблемы.

Comment: Сколько просмотров планируете?

Comment: Какие требования к трансляции? Задержки, интерактивность, поддержка устройствами и программами?